# webview background blurring while scrolling

Tags: android, android-webview

My problem is webview background blurring while scrolling. Background is an image. My code :

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
webview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.regularbackground);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your code :

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: You should read webview from good reference like any book or android developer site.